# Having trouble to implement repository layer in android with retrofit and rxandroid

Tags: android, repository-pattern, rx-java, rx-android, retrofit2

I started to use rxandroid yesterday and trying to make repository layer for api with retrofit and rxandroid. However, I realized that I cannot easily return result from repository to activity or fragment.
With request result I need to make grid adapter and set it to view.
Since I cannot have application context in repository(I think it shouldnt). I came up with idea that pass observable back to presenter.. Is is good practice or Observable object should not be passed around.

[Repository code](https://github.com/intelcoder/Nanodegree-PopularMovieApp/blob/app_dev/app/src/main/java/com/example/fiddlest/nanodegree_movieapp/Repository/RetrofitApi/MovieApiRepository.java)

[Using passed Observable](https://github.com/intelcoder/Nanodegree-PopularMovieApp/blob/app_dev/app/src/main/java/com/example/fiddlest/nanodegree_movieapp/View/Fragment/MovieGridFragment.java) (Observable will be move to presenter later)

Comment: No, passing around `Observable`s it not a problem at all. As for the general architecture: I think it is more usual to keep a single Retrofit object in some long lived object and use that from all your Activities and Fragments - for example, have a look at Jake Wharton's example app https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/api/ApiModule.java where he creates a Retrofit singleton and uses Dagger to inject that.

Comment: Yes I will make my retrofit to be singleton with dagger later. Thank you for answer and link